# Are patents titles required to be unique?

Tags: patent-applications, title

Are patents titles required to be unique, as for instance required for websites addresses?

Take as an example the UK patent [description for a patent](https://assets.publishing.service.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/873877/WS0055_Description_Jan_2020.pdf), and suppose that a patent with title "Bicycle Stabiliser" has been filed in the past.

Can I file a patent introducing a completely novel bicycle stabiliser, but with the same "Bicycle Stabiliser" title?

Comment: As an aside, neither are book titles required to be unique.

Comment: As an aside to the aside: book titles may be protected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, they are not required to be unique.

For examples try any standard product in any patent search engine and you'll find plenty.

Comment: After all, patents are uniquely identified by a number. In fact I think some patent titles are intentionally vague and generic to make searching more difficult.